# Mesomeric effect in -NHCOR and -OR

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, erratum

I've read in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mesomeric_effect&oldid=1011528450) about +M strength of groups which goes:

> –O **-** > –NH2 > **–NHCOR > –OR** > –OCOR > –Ph > –CH3 > –F > –Cl > –Br > –I

Now in every other website states that in terms of +M strength:

[image]  [website->brainly](https://brainly.in/question/10469471)

[image]

[website->Chemistry libretexts](https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Purdue/Purdue%3A_Chem_26200%3A_Organic_Chemistry_II_(Wenthold)/Chapter_15._Reactions_of_Aromatic_Molecules/15.03%3A_Substitution_effects_on_orientation/15.03.1%3A_Theory_of_Directing_effects)

*(And many more)*

## My question:

Can you please verify the series and explain the reason if -OR actually has less activity than -NHCOR?

- Also since in -NH of -NHCOR there is an EWG(Electron withdrawing group) which is -COR which should decrease the +M strength of the group appreciably.

Comment: Just pointing out that you compared to order of -NHCOR with -OR in your reference from wiki.

Comment: @RavirajBhosale thank you for pointing out brother :)

Comment: What I think is +M of -OR must be greater. There will be a cross resonance when  -NHCOR is attached to a conjugated system. Meaning that the lone pair of N is already be in conjugation with the carbonyl group. Another thing is that there is, as you say, -I of carbonyl group.

Comment: @RavirajBhosale yes even I think the information provided in Wikipedia is misleading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check out the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a}$ values of paracetamol (acetaminophen) , it is 9.38 while $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ of para-methoxybenzene is 10.1.

So, $\ce{-OR}$ should exert a greater mesomeric effect as compared to $\ce{-NHCOR}$ making the wikipedia wrong.

**References:**

1. https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Acetaminophen
2. https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/4-Methoxyphenol#section=Ionicity

Answer (score 4):

Hammett $\sigma_m$ and $\sigma_p$ constants are based upon the acid dissociation of benzoic acid and *m*- and *p*-substituted benzoic acids $(\ce{X-C6H4-CO2H})$ in water at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$. They are correlated with  $K_\mathrm{a}$ values of these benzoic acids as shown in few examples in the following table:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\hline
\text{Substituent }(\ce{X})  & \sigma_p & K_\mathrm{a} & \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} & \text{property} \\
\hline
\ce{p-OCH3} & -0.27 & 3.5 \times 10^{-05} & 4.46 & \text{EDG} \\
\ce{p-CH3} & -0.17 & 4.3 \times 10^{-05} & 4.34 & \text{EDG} \\
\ce{H} & 0.00 & 6.46 \times 10^{-05} & 4.19 & \text{Standard} \\
\ce{p-Cl} & +0.23 & 1.10 \times 10^{-04} & 3.96 & \text{EWG} \\
\ce{p-NO2} & +0.78 & 3.90 \times 10^{-04} & 3.41 & \text{EWG} \\
\hline
\end{array}\\
\text{Source: http://research.cm.utexas.edu/nbauld/unit4.htm}
$$

It is safe to say that $\sigma_p$ constants are more reflected on mesomeric effect while $\sigma_m$ constants are more reflected on inductive effect (Ref.1).

Thus, let's look at some of $\sigma_p$ and $\sigma_m$ values:

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\hline
\text{Substituent }(\ce{X})  & \sigma_p & \sigma_m \\
\hline
\ce{N(CH3)2} & -0.83 & -0.15 \\
\ce{NH2} & -0.66 & -0.16 \\
\ce{OH} & -0.37 & +0.12 \\
\ce{OCH3} & -0.27 & +0.12 \\
\ce{CH3} & -0.17 & -0.07 \\
\ce{NHC(=O)CH3} & -0.15 & +0.07 \\
\ce{C6H5}* & -0.01 & +0.06 \\
\ce{H} & 0.00 & 0.00 \\
\ce{OC(=O)Ph} & +0.13 & +0.21 \\
\ce{Cl} & +0.23 & +0.37 \\
\ce{C(=O)CH3} & +0.50 & +0.38 \\
\ce{NO2} & +0.78 & +0.71 \\
\hline
\end{array}\\
\text{*: Indicates that the group is in the most sterically hindered conformation.}\\
\text{Source: Journal of Medicinal Chemistry Reference and others; see Ref.2 & 3 below}
$$

According to $\sigma_p$ values, $+M$ strength of groups are:

$$\ce{-NH2 \gt -OH \gt -OR \gt -CH3 \gt -NH(C=O)R \gt -Ph \gt -OC(=O)R}$$

---

**References:**

1. Corwin Hansch, Albert Leo, Robert W. Taft, "A survey of Hammett substituent constants and resonance and field parameters," *Chem. Rev.* **1991**, *91(2)*, 165–195 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/cr00002a004).
2. Corwin Hansch, Sharon D. Rockwell, Priscilla Y. C. Jow, Albert Leo, and Edward E. Steller, "Substituent Constants for Correlation Analysis," *J. Med. Chem.* **1977**, *20(2)*, 304-306 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/jm00212a024).
3. Corwin Hansch and Albert Leo, In *Substituent Constants for Correlation Analysis in Chemistry and Biology*; Wiley-Interscience: New York, NY, 1979 (ISBN-13: 978-0-471-05062-9).